# Solution to sequence of SDEs

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-pde

For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ let $\mu_n(t,x)$ and $\sigma_n(t,x)$ be a sequence of processes adapted to the filtration of a d-dimensional Brownian motion $W(t)$:
$$
dY_n(t) = \mu_n(t,Y_n(t))dt + \sigma_n(t,Y_n(t))dW(t)
$$
such that $\mu_n \mapsto \mu$ in $L^2$ and $\sigma_n \mapsto \sigma$ in $L^2$.

Then (or under what conditions) does the solutions $Y_n$ to the above sequence of SDEs converge to the solution to the SDE

$$
dY(t) = \mu(t,Y(t))dt + \sigma(t,Y(t))dW(t)?
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assume some structure conditions on $\mu$ and $\sigma$ [these notes](http://www.math.wisc.edu/~kurtz/oxford/oxallpsc.pdf) cover it on page 52 onwards.